# How to update react native header button

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-navigation

I have a screen that gets data of isFavourite which is stored in `useState`. The screen has two buttons one of which is a like/favourite button. I am trying to update the like/favourite button's color based on the state of isFavourite. I am following the doc's [here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/header-buttons/). However, my button doesn't seem to be functioning. i.e. function not logging anything to console.

Here is my screen code;

```
export default function VenueScreen({ navigation, route }) {
  
  const [isFavourite, setIsFavourite] = useState(false);
  
  useEffect(() => {
    navigation.setOptions({
      headerRight: () => (
        <VenueHeaderButtons
          isFavourite={isFavourite}
          handleFavouritePress={() => handleFavoritePress(isFavourite)}
        />
      ),
    });
  }, [navigation, isFavourite, handleFavoritePress]);

  const handleFavoritePress = () => {
    console.log("NOT LOGGING ANYTHING HERE???")
    setIsFavourite((prev) => !prev);
  };
}
```

Here is my VenueButton code;

```
function VenueHeaderButtons({ isFavourite, handleFavouritePress }) {
const heartColor = useMemo(() => {
    return isFavourite ? "red" : textColor;
  }, [isFavourite, textColor]);

  return (
    <View style={containerStyle}>
      <Pressable
        style={buttonStyle}
        onPress={handleFavouritePress}>
        <TouchableOpacity activeOpacity={0.5}>
          <MaterialCommunityIcons
            name="heart-outline"
            size={25}
            color={heartColor}
          />
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </Pressable>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this:

```
function VenueHeaderButtons({ isFavourite, handleFavouritePress }) {
const heartColor = useMemo(() => {
    return isFavourite ? "red" : textColor;
  }, [isFavourite, textColor]);

  return (
    <View style={containerStyle}>
        <TouchableOpacity activeOpacity={0.5} onPress={handleFavouritePress}>
          <MaterialCommunityIcons
            name="heart-outline"
            size={25}
            color={heartColor}
          />
        </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Comment: Yes you are right. My TouchableOpacity was killing the onPress function.